# Turning values into columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Apologies for the vague question name, but I'm not really sure how to call this operation.

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 1, 2],
    'B': [2, 1, 3, 2, 3],
    'C': [3, 2, 1, 3, 1],
})
print(df)
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  3  1  2
# 2  2  3  1
# 3  1  2  3
# 4  2  3  1
```

This data represents a "ranking" of each of the options, `A`, `B` and `C` for each row. So, for example, in row `2`, `C` was the best, then `A`, then `B`. I would like to construct the "inverted" data frame, where, for each row, I have three columns for the `1`, `2` and `3` position of the ranking, with `A`, `B` and `C` being now the data. So, for the example above, the result would be:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({
    1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
    2: ['B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    3: ['C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B'],
})
print(out)
#    1  2  3
# 0  A  B  C
# 1  B  C  A
# 2  C  A  B
# 3  A  B  C
# 4  C  A  B
```

Ideally, each row in `df` should have the three distinct values `1`, `2` and `3`, but there may be cases with repeated values (values out that range don't need to be considered). If possible at all, I would like to resolve this by "concatenating" the names of the options in the same position, and having empty strings or NaN in missing positions. For example, with this input:

```
df_bad = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'B': [2], 'C': [2]})
print(df_bad)
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  2  2
```

I would ideally want to get this output:

```
out_bad = pd.DataFrame({1: ['A'], 2: ['BC'], 3: ['']})
print(out_bad)
#    1   2 3
# 0  A  BC
```

Alternatively, I could settle for just getting one of the values instead of the concatenation.

I have been looking through [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and other functions but I can't figure out the way to get the result I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for duplicate ranking cases such as 2nd example, any solution using `pivot` and `unstack` at the last step will fail. You need `pivot_table` or `crosstab`. As you already figured out solution using `pivot_table`. Here is `crosstab`

```
df2 = df_bad.stack().reset_index(1, name='cols')
pd.crosstab(index=df2.index, columns=df2.cols, values=df2.level_1,
                             aggfunc=''.join).fillna('')

Out[171]:
cols   1   2
row_0
0      A  BC
```

---

Use `stack` and `pivot`

```
df.stack().reset_index(1, name='cols').pivot(columns='cols', values='level_1')

Out[131]:
cols  1  2  3
0     A  B  C
1     B  C  A
2     C  A  B
3     A  B  C
4     C  A  B
```

Comment: This is the closest to the solution I think, I got it to work as I wanted in all cases with `df2 = df.stack().reset_index(1, name='cols'); out = df2.pivot_table(index=df2.index, columns='cols', values='level_1', fill_value='', aggfunc=np.sum)`.

Comment: yeah, as your 2nd case, any solution using `pivot` or `unstack` at the last step will fail. You need `pivot_table` or `crosstab`. I edited to add the `crosstab` solution

Answer (score 8):

You can use [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values[np.argsort(df.values)])
```

---

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  B  C  A
2  C  A  B
3  A  B  C
4  C  A  B
```

Answer (score 7):

here is one way [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=1).set_index(0,append=True)['level_1'].unstack()
Out[89]: 
0  1  2  3
0  A  B  C
1  B  C  A
2  C  A  B
3  A  B  C
4  C  A  B
```

Answer (score 6):

Your first example can be efficiently solved with `argsort` and indexing.

---

```
m = np.argsort(df.to_numpy(), 1)

df.columns.to_numpy()[m]
```

```
array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['B', 'C', 'A'],
       ['C', 'A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['C', 'A', 'B']], dtype=object)
```

The second example is a bit tricker, but still the same idea, I'll update shortly.

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 1, 2],
    'B': [2, 1, 3, 2, 3],
    'C': [3, 2, 1, 2, 1],
})

(df.stack()
   .reset_index()
   .groupby(['level_0',0])
   .level_1.apply(''.join)
   .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
0        1   2    3
level_0            
0        A   B    C
1        B   C    A
2        C   A    B
3        A  BC  NaN
4        C   A    B
```